# use Excel to count numbers in specified range

Tags: excel, function

suppose we have following data

```
23
30
27.5
18
4
11
9
10
16
24
56
90
65
17
19
44
72
```

and i want to count number of elements in range [10-60] ? sure we can  use if for determining if our  value is  in interval,but is there any function in excel like countrange or something like this which takes input as a vector and  also range and returns number of element which fits in that range?thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should also work:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A17;">=10")-COUNTIF(A1:A17;">60")
```

A1:A17 is the range of course.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `COUNTIF`

COUNTIF function counts the number of cells within a range that meet a single criterion (condition) that you specify.

`=COUNTIF(range, criteria)`

Also there is `COUNTIFS`

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-numbers-greater-than-or-less-than-a-number-HP003056117.aspx

Comment: Doesn't this count every entry, plus the entries between 10 and 60?

Comment: @WorakarnIsaratham Yes it does actually. COUNTIFS is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using `COUNTIFS` function

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9, ">=10",$A$2:$A$9,"<=60")
```

[`COUNTIFS`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-countifs-to-evaluate-multiple-count-and-criteria-ranges/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a build in function to do that. You'd need to write one on your own at takes a range of fields, iterates of all elements and increments a predefined return value if a field meets your requirements.

You can read how that's done here: [Creating custom functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx)

Comment: can i use c++ in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the latter part of your question (ie for a number of ranges rather just than a single one) yes, there is an Excel function for this, [=FREQUENCY](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/frequency-HP005209097.aspx).

The answer for [10-60] is `11`, as shown below, but with the upper limits for the bins in ColumnC, one array formula will populate all counts for the ranges selected:

[image: SO19889660 example]